# Change onClick attribute in a Boostrap modal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I open a Bootstrap modal and would like to change the function of the onClick attribute of my button but it doesn't work.

I'm doing it that way:

JavaScript

```
function confirm_del_lot_acid(id){
    modal_confirmer_suppression();
    $j("#confirm_link").attr("onclick", "console.log("+id+")");
}

function modal_confirmer_suppression(){
    $j("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/params_supprimer_element.php");
    $j('#all_modal').modal('show');
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dimiss="modal" onClick="close_modal();">Fermer</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" id="confirm_link" onClick=""><?php echo $confirmation; ?></a>
</div>
```

It works when I use directly the function in the browser console but it looks like I'm not able to modify the modal. I also tried to modify other stuff in the modal and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#confirm_link").attr("onclick", "");
```

then

```
 $("#confirm_link").attr("onclick", "cotnsole.log("+id+")");
```

EDIT
use `$("#confirm_link")` instead of `$j("#confirm_link")`

Comment: can you check in your browser `element attr` that is changed or not ?

Comment: I use $j because of a conflict with Ajax, so i added <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script> in my main page. And i checked in my browser... it didn't changed

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown:

```
$("#confirm_link").click(function(){
     // code 
});
```

Comment: I do it this way to use one single modal for a lot of differents fonctions. It's a modal to confirm a delete. And I have the same modal but differents functions to use with. So I can't define the function called on the button. :(